# Arvixe claims that my physical host is located in Europe eventhough the whois information

Tags: ipv4, whois, geolocation, geoip, traceroute

When I look whois of the site it seems like located in US. 
My site is: www.evdore.com.

1               *   *   *

2   hos-tr1.juniper1.rz13.hetzner.de    213.239.224.1   de  0.145 ms
hos-tr4.juniper2.rz13.hetzner.de    213.239.224.97  de  0.277 ms    0.449 ms

3   core21.hetzner.de   213.239.245.81  de  0.674 ms    0.570 ms
core22.hetzner.de   213.239.245.121 de  0.658 ms

4   core1.hetzner.de    213.239.245.177 de  4.865 ms
core4.hetzner.de    213.239.245.18  de  4.814 ms
core1.hetzner.de    213.239.245.177 de  4.865 ms

5   juniper1.ffm.hetzner.de 213.239.245.5   de  4.909 ms
juniper4.ffm.hetzner.de 213.239.245.1   de  4.903 ms
juniper1.ffm.hetzner.de 213.239.245.5   de  4.909 ms

6   bbr01.xn01.fra01.networklayer.com   80.81.194.167   de  4.892 ms    4.957 ms    4.970 ms

7   ae7.bbr02.xn01.fra01.networklayer.com   50.97.18.219    us  5.431 ms
ae6.dar01.sr01.ams01.networklayer.com   50.97.18.249    us  12.563 ms
ae7.bbr02.xn01.fra01.networklayer.com   50.97.18.219    us  5.431 ms

8   ae1.bbr01.eq01.ams02.networklayer.com   50.97.18.216    us  11.750 ms
po2.fcr01.sr01.ams01.networklayer.com   159.253.158.133 nl  11.830 ms

9   ae5.dar01.sr01.ams01.networklayer.com   50.97.18.237    us  11.084 ms   13.169 ms   11.124 ms

10              *   *   *

11  stats.giraffe.arvixe.com    108.175.157.52  us  14.108 ms   14.159 ms   13.905 ms

They say this:

> "ams01 and ams02 are amsterdam. "159.253.158.131" Running the IP geo
>   location tool for the last hop IPs will show these IPs are in
>   Amsterdam Our IP doesn't show it because we registered it in the US,
>   but our provider in EU has its IPs registered in EU."

But as can be seen latest hop is in US also. Could you help me about my server physical location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoIP lookups **do not** necessarily reflect the physical location of the IP address. GeoIP lookups rely soley on the **whois** information of the netblock. The whois information is often just set to the corporate headquarters of the netblock owner.

The most accurate indicator you have of the physical location of an IP address comes from the hostnames of the hops in your traceroute. You can see from your traceroute that your packets flow through Amsterdam (**ams**) on the 9th hop. You can also see that the ping time difference from the 9th hop to the last hop is only 3ms. From that, you can surmise that your server is located in Amsterdam as well.

However, there is nothing forcing your ISP to include geolocation information in their hostnames nor are there any rules forcing ISPs to put **accurate** geolocation information in their hostnames. Sometimes it requires a bit of investigative work (e.g., running traceroutes from various looking glass servers) to determine the physical location of an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

The last few hops all have `ams` in the name, which stands for Amsterdam.

[GeoIP](http://www.iplocationtools.com/50.97.18.237.html) confirms this as well.

```
IP Address        50.97.18.237
Country Code      NL
Country Name      Netherlands Netherlands
Region Name       Noord-Holland
City Name         Amsterdam
Coordinates       52°22'27"N   4°53'23"E
                  (Latitude: 52.37403, Longitude: 4.88969)

ISP               SoftLayer Technologies Inc.       Domain Name   softlayer.com
Connection Type   T1                                Usage Type    Data Center/Web Hosting/Transit
IDD Code          31                                Area Code     020
Postal Code       1089                              Elevation     12 meters
Local Time        25 Jun, 2015 05:46 PM (UTC +02:00)
Weather Station   Amsterdam (NLXX0002)
MCC               -                                  MNC    -
Mobile Brand Name - 
Permalink         http://www.iplocationtools.com/50.97.18.237.html
```

The server is located in Softlayer's Amsterdam data center.

Comment: Mike, ok but why the last hop is US, if my server is in EU. I couldn't understand that

Comment: What makes you think it is?  From Mike's answer, you know that whatever tool you are using above gets the location of 2 of the 3 .ams addresses wring.  That given, I see no reason to trust it about the last hop.

Comment: The last hop is the IP of the server which was registered in the US. ARIN still has it listed as a US IP due to that but the owners of the IP can route it anywhere in the world they see fit. In may take ARIN several months to pickup on that.

Answer (score -1):

When I ping your site, the IP is from United States, not Amsterdam. Here are your ping result http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=trace&host=www.evdore.com